# How can I remove a folder from the dock?

Tags: folder, plank

Folders containing files can be dragged and pinned to the dock. The problem is there's no going back from there, that is you can't remove folders neither by dragging them off nor from a context menu.

I've found out it's [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/plank/+bug/1010066) (and a quite long-standing one from the look of it). But my problem now is finding a way/workaround to remove a folder I no longer need. I guess some config files may be modified.

Comment: OP can you please remove your comment/edit and make it into an answer?

Comment: Sure thing. Do you think I should also file a bug or update the one I linked above? Also, which project should I target, Plank or Pantheon-dock?

Comment: You *do not* need to file a new issue. It is already report and confirmed. The developers working on Plank are volunteers, so you'll just have to wait until they find the time to address it.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. It looks the original issue described in the bug report has been fixed. Pin any folder - provided it contains few files - to the dock. Now, you can easily drag it off to remove it or unpin it via context menu. The problem arises with a folder containing a certain amount of files; when you click on it (both left and right click) the list of files is too big to be displayed it its entirety so you have scroll bars top and bottom. In this situation you cannot perform any of the actions above unless you get to the bottom of the list. I'll update my question with pics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upon further investigation, I found that the context menu can actually be accessed and from there you can untick "Keep in dock". What fooled me was that I had pinned to the dock a folder containing a great number of files and in order to access the context menu you have to scroll down like forever (or hit the 'End' key). This is not a desirable behavior either. Once you are at the bottom of the list you can drag the folder off, too.

[image]
[image]